# using sql management studio to focus table on database diagram

Tags: ssms

Is there any way to focus table on database diagram in sql management studio without finding it "manually"?

Have tried "Find" tool but it only focus next script related word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is a current feature in the SSMS database diagram tool. You can file a bug to get it added here: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback